# Derivation of de-Sitter solution from Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

The Einstein-Hilbert action for spacetime with only a cosmological constant is given by
$$S=\int\Big[\frac{R}{2}-\Lambda\Big]\sqrt{-g}\ d^4x.$$
I assume a spatially flat FRW metric in Cartesian coordinates with line element
$$ds^2=-dt^2+a^2(t)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2).$$
The Ricci scalar is given by
$$R=6\left\{\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}+\Big(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\Big)^2\right\}$$
and the determinant of the metric is given by
$$g=-a^6.$$
I want to use the calculus of variations to find the form of $a(t)$ for a de-Sitter Universe.

The Einstein-Hilbert action is
\begin{eqnarray}
S &=& \int\Bigg[3\left\{\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}+\Big(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\Big)^2\right\}-\Lambda\Bigg]a^3\ d^4x \\
&=& \int\Big[3\ a^2\ \ddot{a}+3\ a\ \dot{a}^2-\Lambda\ a^3\Big]d^4x
\end{eqnarray}
The extremum of the action is given by the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta a}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{a}}+\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot{a}}=0.$$
We have
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}=6\ a\  \ddot{a}+3\ \dot{a}^2-3\ \Lambda\  a^2$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{a}}=\frac{d}{dt}\Big[6\ a\ \dot{a}\Big]=6\ \dot{a}^2+6\ a\ \ddot{a}$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot{a}}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\Big[3\ a^2\Big]=\frac{d}{dt}\Big[6\ a\ \dot{a}\Big]=6\ \dot{a}^2+6\ a\ \ddot{a}$$
Therefore the Euler-Lagrange equation is
$$6\ a\  \ddot{a}+3\ \dot{a}^2-3\ \Lambda\  a^2=0.$$
I was hoping this equation would have the exponential solution for a de-Sitter Universe given by
$$a(t)=e^{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}\ t}.$$
But this expression does not solve the Euler-Lagrange equation.

What's wrong?

**Addendum**

Oops - Sorry it does solve the EL equation! I must have just slipped up when I plugged in the expression.

$$a=e^{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t}$$
$$\dot{a}=\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}}\ e^{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t}$$
$$\ddot{a}=\frac{\Lambda}{3}\ e^{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t}$$

Substituting into EL
$$6\ a\  \ddot{a}+3\ \dot{a}^2-3\ \Lambda\  a^2=0$$
gives
$$6\times e^{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t}\times \frac{\Lambda}{3}\ e^{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t}+3\times \frac{\Lambda}{3}\times e^{2\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t} - 3\times \Lambda\times e^{2\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t}=0.$$

Comment: Sorry, it does seem to solve the EL equation.  What's the problem?

Comment: Oops - you're right, sorry! Must have just slipped up when I tried to verify the solution to the EL equation last night.